# RHEL6: which package handle systemctl?

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd

When running `systemctl` command on `RHEL6` it gave:

```
# systemctl --version
bash: systemctl: command not found
```

Which package handle it and how can be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `systemd` (so any `systemctl` command) on RHEL 6. It was introduced with RHEL 7.

Comment: Is there a solution to make a process start at system boot?

Comment: @Eng7 please edit your question and add the above question

Comment: @Eng7 This is a new question.

Comment: Using chkconfig command and enable the run level. # chkconfig --level 2345 named on/off. RHEL 6 didnt implement systemctl yet.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered, @Eng7